# Playwright get cookie

Tags: node.js, playwright

I need to get a JSSESSIONID cookie from one page and pass it to another. But when I try to fetch cookie with a playwright I got an empty array. Any ideas?

```
const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
const context = await browser.newContext();
        
const page = await context.newPage();
await page.goto(link);
       
const elementHandle = await page.$('#putfocushere');
await elementHandle.type(searchNumber);
console.log(await context.cookies(page.url()))
```

Comment: What does `await context.cookies()` return? (without URL filtering)

Comment: It returns an empty array

Answer (score 12):

Access it through [`BrowserContext`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-context), which you can get through `page.context()`, e.g.

```
await page.context().cookies();
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing `await context.cookies()` without specifying any origin? More than likely, this is happening because the value returned by `page.url()` isn't an exact match. You can try getting all the cookies and then filtering by your domain.

There is also `context.storageState()` that is now available in playwright, which will return all cookies and localstorage. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/docs/api.md#browsercontextstoragestateoptions).

Comment: *ahem https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-storage-state

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a new context because the browser already has a context. When you try to get the cookies, you need to give the index to the context like so:

```
var cookies = await browser.Contexts[0].CookiesAsync();
```

The index "0" selects the context and gets the cookies